# Sequential AJAX calls in jquery .each iteration

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, html-lists, each

I need to make AJAX calls sequentially using **each** on **li** elements and append the ordered result in a div:

```
  $('#activityListSelected li').each(function (i) {

                var myText= $(this).text().replace(/ /g, "_");

                    // injecting content partial in html
                    $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action(MVC.Area.MyController.MyAction())',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        myText: $(this).text().replace(/ /g, "_"),
                    }),
                    success: function (response) {
                         $('#myDiv').append(response);
                    },

                    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {

                    }
                    });

                    index++;

                });
```

I've noticed that, being the calls asynchronous, the order of the rendered HTMLs is not correct, so I need to know when each AJAX call finish its work to make the subsequent one. I don't want to use "async: false" in AJAX parameters because I can't use the loading layer.

Comment: You must send bulk ids and get done this through single ajax call. And it is absolutely possible. Looping in ajax is not so good idea. But still if you want to go ahead with this then you can use q js library

Comment: 'complete' property of ajax, for identifying whether ajax call is completed or not, may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 function getData() {
     var requests = [];
        $('#activityListSelected li').each(function (i) {
            var promise = $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action(MVC.Area.MyController.MyAction())',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    "myText": currentObj.text().replace(/ /g, "_"),
                }),
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#myDiv').append(response);
                },

                error: function (jqXHR, exception) {

                }
            }).done(function (data) {   //received data!


            });
            requests.push(promise);
        });
        console.log(requests);
        // return a promise that will resolve when all ajax calls are done
        return $.when.apply($, requests);
    }
```

Comment: have you used promise ?

Comment: let me see how to use it, please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164545/discussion-between-andreasperelli-and-negi-rox).